# Incron job is not being executed

Tags: cron, fedora20, incron

I am using incron to monitor one of my file in `/var/www/html` directory. 
output of `incrontab -l`

```
/var/www/html/test IN_ACCESS /home/intel/test.sh
```

This job is supposed to create a file in home directory, But when this job got executed (I opened the web address in browser), no file is created, following line is whon shown in `/var/log/cron` file

```
Jan 20 10:27:57 localhost incrond[26442]: (root) CMD (/home/intel/test.sh)
```

This clearly shows that event had occurred.

**P.S:** If I just run a `/home/intel/test.sh` in CLI its works fine and creates test file, following is my **test.sh** file.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch fm00
```

Answer (score 5):

Mostly this problem occurs due to script file permission and ownership of script files. The same problem was faced by me. I found that my scrip owner was not a super user e.g. root.

So, you have to set the permission and ownership of your scrip as super user. Find below.

First of all edit your crontab as super user.(in RHEL like below)

```
[abc@host] crontab -e
```

and save crontab :wq!

Now set permission for script

```
[abc@host] chmod +x script.sh
[abc@host] chown root:root script.sh
```

Now restart your crontab.(in RHEL like below)

```
[abc@host] /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

Comment: Problem is solved now. I don't know what happened although it was mysterious.

Comment: may be due to above  mistakes explained in answer